# How to do matrix multiplication with ff objects

Tags: r, ffbase, ff

Suppose I have `ff_matrix` (also doesn't work with `ffdf`) objects called `x` and `y`. `x` is a 100*10 matrix and `y` is a 10*1 matrix.

```
library(ffbase)

x <- as.ffdf(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*10),ncol=10)))
y <- as.ffdf(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10))))

x <- ffbase:::as.ff_matrix.ffdf(x)
y <- ffbase:::as.ff_matrix.ffdf(y)
```

However, `x %*% y` will result in `Error in x %*% y : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments`.

Comment: I think "%*%" for ff_matrix objects does not exists yet. You might want to ask this to the author of the ff package.